# A proposition on Mobius map

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk on the complex plane. A function $\varphi: \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ is called a Mobius map if it is analytic, one-to-one,
and onto. We let $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ denote the set of all Mobius maps of $\mathbb{D}$.

Proposition.  $\varphi\in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ if and only if there exists a real number $\theta$ and a point $a\in \mathbb{D}$ such that $$\varphi(z)=e^{\theta}\varphi_a(z), ~~ z\in \mathbb{D},$$ where $\varphi_a(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}$.

How to prove this proposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\varphi_a(0)=a$.

Then, by basic group theory, it suffices to show that rotations are the only automorphisms of $\mathbb D$ that fix the origin. I'll leave this as an exercise for you. (Hint: Use the Schwarz Lemma.)

Comment: So the proof has to rely on group theory? Is there a transparent proof to a beginner? Thanks

Comment: The only group-theoretic observation, which we can make without using the language of groups, is that given an automorphism $\psi$ with $\psi(a)=0$ for some $a$, we can write $\psi=\tau \circ \varphi_a$, where $\tau$ maps $0$ to $0$.